# WPF Toolkit calendar control in a MVVM solution, how to highlight days?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit

From this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx I wanted to create a list of selected days like he did.  Except my list is not static and putting it in the converter seems smelly.  Has anyone done something similar with the WPF toolkit calendar control?  Or are we trying to use this control for something more than what it is intended?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you implement the accepted solution? Do you have code/markup you would be willing to post? It would help me a lot--thanks.

Comment: I did something, I can't remember what now, it wasn't pretty, I think I ended up putting things in the code behind.  I won't be able to check for a week, but i will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a MultiValueConverter which takes a DateTime and a list of special days.